# Listview's getView() isn't working properly when using 2 different kinds of listitem

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

I have a custom Array adapter for a Listview, i am using it for contacts, since i wanted the listview to be more organized i wanted to add a header for the 1st letter of the Contact's name 
This is my current progress:

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        LinearLayout header = null;
        String preLabel = " ";
        char firstChar = ' ';
        final Contact c = Contacts.get(position);
        String label = c.name;
        if(position != 0) {//OOb prevention
            preLabel = Contacts.get(position - 1).name;
            firstChar = label.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        }



        char preFirstChar = preLabel.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        if (listItem == null) {
            //If its the 1st position or the 1st character of the name is different inflate the layout with a header, else inflate the other layout.
            if(position==0 || firstChar != preFirstChar) {

                listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
                header  = (LinearLayout) listItem.findViewById(R.id.section);
                setSection(header, label);
            }else{
                listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list2, parent, false);
            }
        }//Etc etc
```

I don't think its relevant to add any more code than this and even in the case that my logic to determine when to put a header is wrong this is having a weird behaviour since when i scroll down to the point where the view is not visible or destroyed when i scroll back up the position 0 has no header.

If i keep doing the same suddenly it fixes itself and now the 1st position again has a header, scroll again and now it doesn't why is this happening? 
Is there another method that the adapter uses to create the views?
Does it try to predict which layout it will use for it to be faster?

Visual reference of the error:

[image: Desc]

As you can see the position 0 (for the sake of simplicity i put the position number in the textview instead of the contact's name) has a header at the start and after scrolling a bit it just, disappears, and then it reappears.

Comment: RecyclerView  discards the views when they are not visible and recreate it when it is visible again, so its like a dynamic load based on your scroll.  I think the way you're chossing the view type perhaps is not optimized, if you do it better it can load your views faster

Comment: Does listview use recyclerview?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your comment

Comment: Isn't better to do a generic ListView, than you add your Contacts, and before you load it on an adapter, you add Strings representing your header, then in your getView you just have to check if that position is a String type or Contact type to inflate your corresponding view. Idk, i still think that this way you're doing is not optimized

Comment: Im just inflating a different layout. But even if that was just not optimal at all i could change it but my question remains, why does that happen? Is it a bug? Is there a reason that i don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll and views get out of visible area, the ListView will re-use the same inflated Views for other locations in the list.

So if you have logic in your `getView` method that may sometimes inflate `R.layout.a` and sometimes inflate `R.layout.b` that can lead to trouble, because then you might get a `convertView` that you need to re-use that is of type `a` but you need a view of type `b` for this specific position in the list.

The solution is to use `ViewType`s, which is how you tell the ListView that you have two different types of layouts, and then it knows when it can recycle a certain type and with which `View`.

basically you should return override `getViewTypeCount()` and return 2 (you have two types of layouts), and move the logic of checking if we need a header or not to `getItemViewType(int position)`.

See here: [Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row)